# Como implementar Mouseover o hover, con laravel y vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo una lista que tiene implementado con vue drag and drop, pero a la vez quisiera implementar esta otra función de JS pero en vue y laravel, estoy intentando con un boton pero de igual manera si se puede con otros elentos esta bien, empeze con esto

```
 <button
        @mouseover="btn='info'"
        @mouseleave="btn='primary'"
        :class='"btn btn-block btn-"+btn'>
        {{ btn }}
    </button>
```

y en mi etiqueta li

```
:class='"btn btn-block btn-"+btn'
```

quedando de este modo

```
 <draggable class="list-group min-height" :list="mSemestreINew" :options="{animation:200, group:'posx'}" :elemt="'ul'" @add="onAdd($event, '1')" @change="update">
         <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(materia, index) in mSemestreINew" :key="materia.id" :data-id="materia.id" :class='"btn btn-block btn-"+btn'>
           <div><strong>Materia: {{ materia.nombre }}   </strong></div>
           <div><small>Cred:{{ materia.creditos }}</small></div>
        </li>
 </draggable>
```

Entonces intento hacer que ciertas materias se resalten de un color y otras de otro etc..., La situación es que aun no encuentro la manera de poder implementar esta logica, porque lo que hace es que me resalta en toda la lista y no en ciertos elementos.

Sin pasar el mouse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el mouse se posa sobre el boton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un ejemplo de como deberia de ser pero con vuejs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para poder lograr lo que quieres, en base a lo que me has dicho. La solución a lo que buscas es esta

```css
.list-group-item {
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.list-group-item.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #0389ff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```
methods: {
  hover: function(id) {
    var _class = ".list-group-item.materia" + id;
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(_class);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function (el) {
      if (!el.classList.contains('active')) {
        el.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        el.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Y tu html quedaría así:

```html
<draggable class="list-group min-height" :list="mSemestreINew" :options="{animation:200, group:'posx'}" :elemt="'ul'" @add="onAdd($event, '1')" @change="update">
         <li :class="'list-group-item materia'+materia.id" v-for="(materia, index) in mSemestreINew" :key="materia.id" @mouseover="hover(materia.id)" @mouseleave="hover(materia.id)">
           <div><strong>Materia: {{ materia.nombre }}   </strong></div>
           <div><small>Cred:{{ materia.creditos }}</small></div>
        </li>
</draggable>
```

Comment: Comprendo esto pero, a todo esto pienso hacer el hover con diferentes botoenes y que estos mismos hagan el hover cuando paso sobre dichos botones, pero cambien el "color" con respecto a un ID

Comment: En todo caso entonces solo seria necesario usar los eventos del mouse en los elementos `li`, el botton seria innecesario al menos que lo utilizes para ocultar y mostrar las lista de materias. PD: actualize mi respuesta

Comment: Además de que no necesitarías usar javascript sino sólo `css`

Comment: Edito la pregunta para que veas un ejemplo de como deberia de ser  y no se si se haga con funciones y metodos

Comment: Cambie totalmente mi respuesta. Y como dije, no necesitas ese `button` ni usar javascript para cambiar la apariencia de un elemento.

Comment: SI hasta alli esta todo bien, pero lo que intento hacer como en la imagen, que si seleciono un elemento se seleccionen los elementos en comun, por ejemplo boton amarillo con id 3, al pasar el mouse seleccione todos los elementos con id 3, ya que pueden estar desordenados u ordenados

Comment: Ah pues eso hubieses dicho en tu pregunta, por que esta bastante enrredosa

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101147/discussion-between-rimuru-tempest-and-dohko19).

Answer (score 0):

Crea una propiedad de `data` que almacene el `id` de la materia en `@mouseover`.

En `@mouseleave` devuelve la propiedad a `null`.

Después utiliza esa propiedad para calcular la clase con la variante del botón.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      materias: [{
          id: 1,
          titulo: 'Física'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          titulo: 'Química'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          titulo: 'Matemáticas'
        }
      ],

      hoverButtonId: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getButtonComputedClass(materiaId) {
      return `btn btn-block btn-${this.hoverButtonId === materiaId ? 'info': 'primary'}`
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.btn-primary {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.btn-info {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Materias:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="materia in materias"
      :key="materia.id"
     >
      <button
        @mouseover="hoverButtonId = materia.id"
        @mouseleave="hoverButtonId = null"
        :class="getButtonComputedClass(materia.id)"
       >
         {{ materia.titulo }}
       </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Usare como llave o `id` otro campo de la base de datos, pero tiene que ser dinamico ya que los datos son de la BD

Comment: hay alguna manera de pasar todos los id al method? de manera dinamica?